# User own account, cancel account button not showing on edit form

Tags: 8, users, forms

I'm using Drupal 8, on my website I have 2 users roles, both can delete their own data, on role 1 cancel account button show on the edit form in both languages, Portuguese and English(default), but on role 2 it only shows up in the language the account was created, both have the right permissions, there is no preprocess on the form that either removes or makes the access false.
Any idea of what it could be, has anyone had a similar problem, how do I fix it?

Comment: Strip all CSS with a browser tool and see if button shows up.

Comment: It's not hidden by css, the html element is not created, so its probably something else.

Comment: Are the users able to change their site language?